# Word or Phrase for a lie being told to force someone to do something?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a single word or phrase that has the meaning of a "lie that is told to force someone into a specific course of action".

For example, if someone tells you that a restaurant is going out of business, in a ploy to convince you to go there. Later you may tell your friend:

> You `lied` to me!

Is there a better word or phrase for this type of lie?

Comment: Sounds like a *pretext*, to me, and a false one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was a end goal in mind - which was to force the person to go to the restaurant -, I'd suggest **manipulate** as the word.

***manipulate*** (according to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/manipulate))

> *noun*
>
> to manage or influence skillfully, especially in an unfair manner
>
> 'You manipulated me!'

You could call it a **manipulative** lie.

Comment: ah, yeah that sounds right!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest,

*Aw, you really **took me for a ride!***

> take someone for a ride: *Fig.* to deceive someone. [McGraw-Hills Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+for+a+ride)

*You **strung me along** all right with your restaurant-going-out-of-business story!*

> string someone along: to fool, cheat, or deceive someone [AHD of Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/string+along)

Comment: Thanks, but I feel like "take someone for a ride" doesn't have the negative connotation that I was going for. However I realize that was not in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider **deceit**.

> Definition: the act or practice of deceiving; concealment or
>   distortion of the truth for the purpose of misleading; duplicity;
>   fraud; cheating.

.

> Example: *Although telling the truth and being understood are
>   important in our romantic relationships, secrecy and deceit are just
>   as essential as truth and honesty*.